# Receive Amazon SNS Notification with Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, http-post

I set up an S3 Bucket to send SNS push notifications to my rails app in the form of an HTTP Post request. However, I don't know how to get rails to process this request / message.  Do I need to build an API to receive HTTP Post Requests from outside the Rails app? Or is there a simpler / better way to do this?

I'm new to Rails, so I could be going down the wrong path here, if so please inform me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### The answers to your questions are:

> Do I need to build an API to receive HTTP Post Requests from outside the Rails app?

Yes. You might consider using [generators](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rails-generate) (`rails g controller`).

> Or is there a simpler / better way to do this?

No

Comment: Thank you @Uzbekjon. Just to be completely clear, can I use generators to build an API? I've used generators to make  standard controllers, but I've never built an API.

Comment: Yeap, they are basically the same thing. In Rails 5 you can inherit from trimmed down controller to build your API without views, etc. But still, conceptually they are the same thing.

Comment: Great. Thanks for the helpful response.